# Asus UX303L with Arch Linux: Mouse Jittering when Plugged In

Tags: laptop, mouse, arch-linux

My dad recently gave me one of his old ASUS UX303L laptops. I formatted his machine and put Arch Linux on there. I noticed, however, that the mouse jitters whenever it is plugged in and I have my finger on the touch pad (i.e. moves around erratically and sometimes infers mouse clicks) making it virtually unusable to use. When the laptop is not plugged in the mouse works just fine.

I noticed that my dad had a third-party aftermarket charger, so I thought perhaps that was causing issues, however after buying the official charger from ASUS that did nothing to ameliorate the problem.

Any ideas what may be going on and how I could fix it?

**Update 03-02-2024:** I noticed today that not only will the mouse jitter if the laptop is plugged in, but also if I'm holding the power cable, even if it's unplugged. I'm not certain about the following, but the jittering seems worse when I hold the connector portion of the power cable, but even holding the insulated part will cause it to jitter some. Not sure if this extra information will help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Try updating the Mouse Driver (for Linux) to see if that helps.

Comment: I have the libinput package installed, and it is updated every time I update my system (approximately 2 hours ago). Is there something else I need to be doing beyond that?

Comment: I am not sure. If that does not fix the mouse then it may be the age of the laptop.

Comment: I'm not sure. My dad stated he doesn't recall having this issue before giving it to me, and given that it's only doing this when plugged in I wonder if it's something solvable.

Comment: It probably had Windows before you installed Linux.